# How to deploy a Smart Contract in Ethereum on Azure?

Tags: remix, metamask, dapps, microsoft-azure

Iam trying to deploy a smart contract in Azure's Ethereum on Azure. I have created a blockchain in that but now I need to deploy a smart contract and design a UI for the same. I want to use Remix to deploy the contract because I have connected it to the RPC end point of the blockchain I have created in Ethereum on Azure. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can use truffle framework for deploying contracts.

Comment: Yeah I have heard about truffle framework but can we use our private blockchain in it? I think it contains test accounts to deploy contracts.

Comment: Yes, you can use private blockchain with it.